# SQL Server Configuration Manager - Cannot connect to WMI Provider

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am trying to run the SQL Configuration Manager and get this error:

[image]

The [typical solution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956013) is not working. Nor are any of the associated ones: running cmd as admin or changing mofcomp to mofcomp.exe. I keep getting an Access denied, 0x80070005 error despite having granted full control to sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof as well as its parent folders to the users & admins on the computer.

Please help.

[image: Permissions]

[image: Error]

Comment: Peculiar that running the cmdshell as admin to execute the mofcomp command still ran into permission issue. What version/flavor of Windows is this? Also, the ACLs for your sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof file seems to be missing a couple of entries that should look something like "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" and "SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$Hostname". Both should have been added during setup. Try adding them manually. Both have "Read & Execute" and "Read" permissions on the files, and "List folder contents" on the Shared folder. Btw, both are localhost security groups, not domain

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. Any idea where I can find those entries?

Comment: That might be the reason. SQL Server 2016 is not supported on Windows 7. Need Windows 8 or higher. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx for full list of supported OS'es.The "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" group was introduced in Windows 8. The SQLServer... security group should be there. From the Security tab in file properties (your first image), Edit then Add and Change location to your local machine. Click on Advanced and Find Now. You'll see all local groups on your box. That said, find a machine or VM with a supported OS. Who knows what else won't work on Win7

Comment: You're right. I think earlier versions of Server 2016 CTP were available to Windows 7. Anyway, I uninstalled all instances of SQL and reinstalled 2012 & 2014. Still getting the error, though.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to your SQL version’s shared directory (cd ):

```
SQL 2008:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\  
SQL 2008 R2:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\  
SQL 2012:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\  
SQL 2014:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\
```

Then run the following command:

```
mofcomp sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof
```

Comment: Running cmd **as administrator** will solve the Access Denied error when running the command.

Comment: Works like magic !  After this, I can now run SQL Server Configuration Manager.  I'm using SQL 2012